# Adding random numbers

Tags: probability

I haven't taken statistics or calculus, but I'm curious: if you take $100$ perfectly random numbers from $-1$ to $1$ and add them, how close would it be to $0$? How about adding $10000$ perfectly random numbers from $-1$ to $1$? How about  infinity ($\infty$)?

Comment: The sum of $n$ such numbers scales like $\sqrt n$, by a result called the central limit theorem. Is this your question?

Comment: @Landuros "Intuitively, the numbers should sum to roughly 0" No. Sum $\ne$ mean.

Comment: @Did The OP asks for the sum of the numbers between $-1$ and $1$: " random numbers from $-1$ to $1$ and *add* them". I am fully aware that the sum is not equal to the mean.

Comment: @Landuros "I am fully aware that the sum is not equal to the mean" Great. Why pretend wrongly that "the numbers should sum to roughly 0", then?

Comment: @Did If it pleases you, I shall remove that comment. But I am still convinced summing all the numbers between $-1$ and $1$ will give you $0$.

Comment: @Landuros What pleases me or displeases me is rather irrelevant. What could be seen as relevant by some is that your comment is mathematically wrong. Your last comment now makes clear that you envision summing **every** real number in the interval. Such an operation is irrelevant to the question and well known to be impossible to define mathematically.

Comment: @Did Ok, I accept my mistake. I was only trying to help, hence I only posted a comment, not an answer. The OP's last sentence implies that he/she wants to know the sum of every real number in the interval, which was what I tried to answer. Sure, it is impossible, but one might consider what $\int^1_{-1}x dx$ evaluates to. I'm only posing some thoughts for someone else to answer the question. Anywho, since you're so critical of my work, what are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @Landuros "The OP's last sentence implies that he/she wants to know the sum of every real number in the interval" No, please read the question better. Actually, the OP describes rather accurately a well known probabilistic setting (which you seem to be unaware of). "I'm only posing some thoughts for someone else to answer the question" Your now deleted comment was much more assertive than that, **which is highly objectionable**. "what are your thoughts on the problem?" See my first comment (if the words in it ring no bell in your mind, somehow I think this is **your** problem, not mine).

Comment: @Did My good sir, I accept defeat. Your faultless mathematical and ethical logic has allowed my primitive brain to assimilate with your level of absolute understanding. Perhaps it is time to take a break from this discussion, no?

Comment: @Landuros Indeed. But a defeat? I see nobody who suffered a defeat here. Only a mathematical misconception did, *and this is good*.

Comment: This page does explains something, thanks did:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: i'm really stupid so i just ran a test on my computer and with more iterations the sum gets really large

Comment: by the way I was curious about this because I wanted to see how initializing random zero centered weights in a neural network would affect the input into the activation depending on the number of neurons

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly random should be defined.

To answer your question we can say that if you repeat selecting $100$ numbers randomly from $-1$ to $1$, many times, and record the sums, then these sums are approximately normally distributed with the mean of $0$

Comment: The OP is asking about the sums, not the averages.

Comment: @Did Fixed it per your comment.

Comment: Not really. Sorry.

Comment: @dandan The more iterations the less stretched out the sum or the average would be.

Comment: I dont think thats true, but I probably wasn't clear by saying "stretched out"

Answer (score -1):

If by perfectly random you mean that each number is independent of the other number and have identical probabilities of being some value, there is a famous law called "The Law of Large Numbers" that states if you have infinite samples, the empirical average of all of those numbers will equal the true average.

To be more specific, Let $X_i$ be the $i^{th}$ sample that you pick between $[-1,1]$. The empirical average is $\frac{1}{n}\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}} X_i$ which goes to $0$ *exponentially* as $n$ grows large. The exact rate is given by Hoeffding's Inequality, which when applied to this problem states that

$$|\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}X_i| \geq n \sqrt{2 \ln \frac{2}{\delta}}$$  with probability $1 - \delta$. So if you just plug in the amount of error you allow into $\delta$ you can get the minimal number of samples you need.

Comment: You mentioned that the sum is of order $n$ with vanishing probability. This answers only partially the OP's query, especially since much more is known...

Comment: The question is about (1) how close the sum is to 0 when adding a finite number of random variables and (2) what happens when you add infinite random variables. What other argument could you use, other than concentration inequalities and the latter by (strong) Law of Large Numbers, to answer this question?

Comment: The Central Limit Theorem would not be applicable to this question because it is a result on convergence (in distribution), whereas the question is asking for a sum of finite random variables.

Comment: Quite wrong. Actually the CLT answers exactly the question the OP is asking, which is to know what a sum of a large number of centered i.i.d. random variables looks like.